# Finding MSA for [Cityname, Statename]?

Tags: r, package, spatial, matching

I'm looking for an R package that helps me to find the respective Metropolitan Statistical Areas (MSA) for input data in the form of [Cityname, State Abbreviation]. For instance: *"New York, NY", "San Francisco, CA"*. I do not have: County name, ZIP Code, FIPS, or anything else.

What I found:

**MSA to County Relationships** (2015) are provided by the [U.S. Census](https://www.census.gov/geographies/reference-files/time-series/demo/metro-micro/delineation-files.html), as "Core based statistical areas (CBSAs), metropolitan divisions, and combined statistical areas (CSAs)". A "**Principal cities of metropolitan and micropolitan statistical areas**" (2015) list is available [on the same page](https://www.census.gov/geographies/reference-files/time-series/demo/metro-micro/delineation-files.html). In worst case, I imagine, one could take the second list, attach the state code to the "Principal City Name" field and then match the corresponding string with an MSA.

Before trying that, it would be good to know whether this problem has been solved already? I did not find the desired function in the [noncensus](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/noncensus/noncensus.pdf) or [USCensus2010](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UScensus2010/UScensus2010.pdf) package.

**Question therefore**: Do you know a package that matches (Principal) City with MSA?

Thanks!