# R package "acs": Get county name, FIPS?

Tags: r, maps, matching, choropleth, census

in search for a solution to an [unsolved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505884/finding-msa-for-cityname-statename), I came across the `acs` package. I assume, there's no way within the choropleth package to get any county information from data in the format `[city, state]`. That's why pre-processing with acs needs to be done.

I tried following code to get the county information on a city:

```
library(acs)
geo.lookup(state="CA", place="San Francisco")

> geo.lookup(state="CA", place="San Francisco")
  state state.name          county.name place               place.name
1     6 California                 <NA>    NA                     <NA>
2     6 California San Francisco County 67000       San Francisco city
3     6 California     San Mateo County 73262 South San Francisco city
```

As we know, cities can be part of different counties. Most likely, I will go with the second

```
> geo.lookup(state="CA", place="San Francisco")[2,]

  state state.name          county.name place         place.name
2     6 California San Francisco County 67000 San Francisco city
```

by default.

**My question:**
Is there a way to get the state abbreviation, county name and county FIPS, too? I could not find the answer in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/acs/acs.pdf).

Also, for further processing (matching with choroplethr), the last "County" in `county.name` and "city" in `place.name` need to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to add the state abbreviation, county name, and county FIPS to your example. R has built-in variables for state names and state abbreviations. For the FIPS codes, I read a csv file from the Census Bureau's website.

```
library(acs)
library(tidyverse)

states <- cbind(state.name, state.abb) %>% tbl_df()

fips <-
  read_csv(
    "https://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/reference/codes/files/national_county.txt",
    col_names = c("state.abb", "statefp", "countyfp", "county.name", "classfp")
  )

query <- geo.lookup(state = "CA", place = "San Francisco")[2, ] %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  left_join(states, by = "state.name") %>%
  left_join(fips, by = c("county.name", "state.abb"))

query

# # A tibble: 1 x 9
# state state.name          county.name place         place.name state.abb statefp countyfp classfp
# <chr>      <chr>                <chr> <int>              <chr>     <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>
#   1     6 California San Francisco County 67000 San Francisco city        CA      06      075      H6
```

As you note at the end of your question, you may need to clean up this data a bit more to make it fit `choroplethr`.

Comment: That works pretty well. Looks like I need to merge statefp+countyfp and remove the first "0" in order to match with choroplethr. One last: Can I also get the MSA fips code through this? Improvement idea: Instead of locading Census csv: `install.packages('tigris')
library(tigris)
data(fips_codes)`

Comment: (Actually, I currently have no idea whether I could visualize the MSA/CBSA shapes. It's called `cbsa` in choroplethrZip's `zip.regions.` but I haven't found any example.)